# Format Date in Bind Statement inside a ListView

Tags: .net, asp.net, listview

is there a way that I can format a Date binded in a ListView?

I have this snippet of ListView

```
<ListView ID="lvView" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        //... some bounded data
        <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RequiredDate") %>' />
        //... another bounded data
    </ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Since `RequiredDate` is a `DateTime` it will display somethine like this `10/20/2010 11:08:55 AM`

What I want is to Format that date to output something like this `Oct. 20, 2010`.  Normally if it is a DateTime I can write something like this `requiredDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")`  but inside the ListView binded data I cannot do that.

I don't want to use OnItemDatabound. I just want it to be formatted inline.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Should be like...

```
Text='<%# Bind("RequiredDate", "{0:MMM dd, yyyy}") %>'
```

Comment: I have tried this → Text='<%# Bind("Date", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}") %>'> ... But still get this format: "3/1/2012 1:00:00 PM". What am I doing wrong??? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
Text='<%# Bind("DateOfBirth", "{0:MMM dd, yyyy}") %>'
```