# Date format in gridview

Tags: asp.net, date, gridview, master-pages, master-detail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format Date in Bind Statement inside a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974481/format-date-in-bind-statement-inside-a-listview)

I have modified a master detail gridview example as per my requirement.  It is working fine but date format in one of cell is displaying as "12/12/2012 12:00:00 AM". I just want to show only "12/12/2012". Please help, code is as below"

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date of Failure" SortExpression="Failure_date" >
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="EditFailure_date" runat="server" Columns="20" MaxLength="50" Text='<%# Bind("Failure_date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Failure_dateRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="EditFailure_date" Display="Dynamic"  ErrorMessage="Can not be blank" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 </EditItemTemplate>
 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
 <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="Failure_date" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("Failure_date") %>' ></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the format that you should use:

```
<%# Bind("Failure_date", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>
```

Comment: It is also working after placing " before {. Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by passing the format to the 2 Bind parameter.

```
Text='<%# Bind("Failure_date","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'
```